# Short Science Fiction story, told in a series of letters

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This was a short story told in a series of letters.  The protagonist starts by writing a letter to a utility company about an error in his bill.  By the last letter he is on death row trying to get his sentence commuted.  Each letter is slightly misunderstood.  I think it's from the late 60's and may have been in anthology like "Orbit".

Comment: It's a very Douglas Adams' "Bureaucracy"-sounding story and if someone can identify it, I'd like to read it!

Comment: I think Vonda N. McIntyre's "Recourse, Inc." (published in *Alternities* [1974], also available in *Fireflood and Other Stories*) might have involved correspondence with a computer similar to Dickson's "Computers Don't Argue". (Had thought the story was by Silverberg, but a friend remembered the title "Recourse, Inc." and Google found it as a story by McIntyre. I do not have access to the story and could not find any plot summary.)

Comment: I see your question has already been answered, but just in case you're interested, the standard literary term for a story told in letters (or other documents) is an "epistolary novel", see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistolary_novel

Answer (score 32):

["Computers Don't Argue"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41533) by [Gordon R. Dickson](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?24).

**This was a short story told in a series of letters.**

This classic story has been reprinted in [many anthologies](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41533) including [*Space Mail*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?31414), an anthology of sci-fi stories told in letters.

**The protagonist starts by writing a letter to a utility company about an error in his bill.**

A book club, actually. The Treasure Book Club. It starts like this:

> Dear Sirs:
> I wrote you recently about the computer punch card you sent billing me for "Kim," by Rudyard Kipling. I did not open the package containing it until I had already mailed you my check for the amount on the card. On opening the package, I found the book missing half its pages. I sent it back to you, requesting either another copy or my money back. Instead, you have sent me a copy of "Kidnapped," by Robert Louis Stevenson. Will you please straighten this out?
> I hearby return the copy of "Kidnapped."
> Sincerely yours,
> Walter A. Child

**By the last letter he is on death row trying to get his sentence commuted.**

Yep. He is actually sentenced to death for the kidnap-murder of Robert Louis Stevenson:

> To: Judge Alexander J. McDivot's Chambers
> Dear Jack:
> Ref: Judgment No. 456789. The victim in this kidnap was apparently slain.
> From the strange lack of background information on the killer and his victim, as well as the victim's age, this smells to me like a gangland killing. This for your information. Don't quote me. It seems to me, though, that Stevenson—the victim—has a name that rings a faint bell with me. Possibly, one of the East Coast Mob, since the association comes back to me as something about pirates—possibly New York dockage hijackers—and something about buried loot.
> As I say, above is only speculation for your private guidance. Any time I can help . . .
> Best,
> Tony Malagasi
> Records Division

The Governor issues a pardon in the nick of time, but:

> To: Governor Hubert Daniel Willikens
> Re: Pardon issued to Walter A. Child, July 1, 198-
> Dear State Employee:
> You have failed to attach your Routing Number.
> PLEASE: Resubmit document with this card and form 876, explaining your authority for placing a TOP RUSH category on this document. Form 876 must be signed by your Departmental Superior.
> RESUBMIT ON: Earliest possible date ROUTING SERVICE office is open. In this case, Tuesday, July 5, 198-
> WARNING: Failure to submit form 876 WITH THE SIGNATURE OF YOUR SUPERIOR may make you liable to prosecution for misusing a Service of the State Government. A warrant may be issued for your arrest.
> There are NO exceptions. YOU have been WARNED.

**Each letter is slightly misunderstood.**

Or more than slightly. An important point is that all this misunderstanding is done by or with the help of computers, hence the title.

**I think it's from the late 60's and may have been in anthology like "Orbit".**

First published in [*Analog*, September 1965](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?56817+c), reprinted in [many anthologies](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41533), but not in the [*Orbit*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbit_(anthology_series)) series, which was a series of [original-stories anthologies](http://www.sfsite.com/columns/rich55.htm).

Comment: The Post Office did not lose any of the letters, so it is fantasy.