# Computer makes mistake over a late library book

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a short story about a man who forgets to return his library book.  A computerised system takes over and everything goes from bad to worse.  The book he did not return is 'Kidnapped' by Robert Louis Stevenson, so the man ends up on a kidnapping charge, which changes to a murder charge when the computer learns that RLS is dead.  It must be from the 60s or 70s.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Short Science Fiction story, told in a series of letters](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/41518/short-science-fiction-story-told-in-a-series-of-letters)

Comment: @Ward No. We have a [clear policy](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7065/closing-story-ident-questions-as-duplicates-where-theres-no-acceptance) on when to close story-ID questions as duplicates, and in this case neither answer has been accepted or acknowledged as correct.

Comment: It's also an entirely different question.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet - The question may be somewhat different, but we close questions as duplicates when the *answers* are the same.

Comment: Is this appropriate for SF&F?  Sounds like [reality](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/03/25/us/man-rents-vhs-tape-doesnt-return-it-ends-up-in-handcuffs.html?_r=0), not fiction.  (Note for later readers: This article is from the day after the question was posted.)

Comment: @Richard: How odd.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet - It can seem a little daunting (at first) but it works for us. It means that two questions that are *superficially* different can be closed if the answer for one could just be recycled.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[Computers Don't Argue](http://www.dave.rainey.net/calendars/dystopias/process3.html) by Gordon R Dickson.

> I wrote you recently about the computer punch card you sent, billing
>   me for "Kim,' by Rudyard Kipling. I did not open the package
>   containing it until I had already mailed you my check for the amount
>   on the card. On opening the package, I found the book missing half its
>   pages. I sent it back to you, requesting either another copy or my
>   money back. Instead, you have sent me a copy of "Kidnapped," by Robert
>   Louis Stevenson. Will you please straighten this out?

later

> POLICE DEPARTMENT, PANDUK, MICHIGAN.
>   TO POLICE DEPARTMENT CHICAGO ILLINOIS.
>   CONVICTED SUBJECT A. (COMPLETE FIRST NAME UNKNOWN) WALTER, SOUGHT HIRE IN CONNECTION REF. YOUR NOTIFICATION OF JUDGMENT FOR KIDNAP OF CHILD NAMED ROBERT LOUIS STEVENSON, ON NOV. 16, 2000.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/41518/short-science-fiction-story-told-in-a-series-of-letters) with unaccepted answer.

Comment: @user14111 - it's a shame no-one supported my proposal to close obvious dupes... :-)

Comment: @Richard The answers have the same book, but as the OP in the other question never came back and marked it as the answer we can't be 100% sure that it is correct for that question.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf - That may well be true, but the reason User14111 and I have gold tag badges is that when we're both 99% certain, the odds of us being right is pretty darned high.