Man is detained by robot judges and is sentenced to death but hopeful because execution is done by a human
I'm looking to ID a short story about a dystopian future where human beings are judged and sentenced by machines. The protagonist, a man detained by robot judges, faces a death sentence. Throughout the story, he grapples with the mechanical nature of his judgment and the depersonalization that comes with it. However, he finds a sliver of hope in the notion that the execution itself must be carried out by a human.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Was it in a magazine, an anthology, or online?

Long time ago (we are talking about 30 years ago or so, in a book or sci-fi stories. Don’t remember which one.

I tried using ChatGPT to ID, and it said that it’s Executioner by John D MacDonald, but i can only find “Executioners” book by that author and the plot is completely different…

Don't use ChatGPT for IDs, it's a huge pile of hallucinations.

Eh, I've found stuff with it before. As long as you stay skeptical and don't automatically blame yourself when it doesn't work, it's pretty useful.

It's a long shot, but might it be this one ... https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/41518/short-science-fiction-story-told-in-a-series-of-letters?
